# Is the "Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree" error related to using the same Provider?

Tags: flutter, provider

I faced this error

```
Duplicate GlobalKeys detected in widget tree.
```

The relevant error-causing widget was (marked with comment):

```
child: Consumer<EntryModel>(
  builder: (context, model, _) {
    return ListView.separated( // error is here
      itemCount: model.items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CardListEntry(index: index, table: table);
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const Divider();
      },
    );
  },
),
```

where `CardListEntry` uses `EntryModel` again

```
class _CardListEntryState extends State<CardListEntry> {
  late final EntryModel model;
  int get index => widget.index;
  String get table => widget.table;
  bool visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    model = Provider.of<EntryModel>(context, listen: false);
    super.initState();
  }
```

and the very first error message in console was

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library ==========
The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b715](state: RawGestureDetectorState#720e7(gestures: [vertical drag], behavior: opaque)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6728 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.
```

Am I using the same `EntryModel` provider type here correctly or is it related to something else?